# “Add to homescreen” link not Found in Chrome DevTools

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Hello everyone i'm trying to build my first PWA App, but when i want to simulate `add to home screen` behavior when i attached my pc and mobile together i can't find `add to home screen in Manifest in under Identity section` [my developerTool Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNIQa.png)

and here is my Manifest File

```
{
"name": "Instgram As Progressive Web App",
"short_name": "PWAGram",
"icons": [
{
"src": "/src/images/icons/app-icon-48x48.png",
"type": "image/png",
"sizes": "48x48"
},
{
"src": "/src/images/icons/app-icon-96x96.png",
"type": "image/png",
"sizes": "96x96"
},
{
"src": "/src/images/icons/app-icon-144x144.png",
"type": "image/png",
"sizes": "144x144"
},
{
"src": "/src/images/icons/app-icon-192x192.png",
"type": "image/png",
"sizes": "192x192"
},
{
"src": "/src/images/icons/app-icon-256x256.png",
"type": "image/png",
"sizes": "256x256"
},
{
"src": "/src/images/icons/app-icon-384x384.png",
"type": "image/png",
"sizes": "384x384"
},
{
"src": "/src/images/icons/app-icon-512x512.png",
"type": "image/png",
"sizes": "512x512"
}
],
"start_url": "/index.html",
"scope": ".",
"display": "standalone",
"orientation": "portrait-primary",
"prefer_related_applications": false,
"background_color": "#FFF",
"theme_color": "#3f51b1",
"description": "A simple Instgram Clone, Implementing a lot of PWA",
"dir": "ltr",
"lang": "en-US"
}
```

Am I doing Something Wrong ? 
Thanks In Advance .

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool?

Comment: You may need to do a production build and push the contents of the /dist folder to an HTTPS host. There are free ones like Glitch.me that you can use for play/testing.

Comment: @Mathias I'm Using Now Local Host which is the only exception For Service Worker.

Comment: To test A2HS you need to have an HTTPS URL

Comment: @Mathias Yes I know But also i Can Test it in local host

Comment: You can test most things with the localhost, but until you test with HTTPS, you do not know if A2HS works properly.